# How to select only one item from all search items?

Tags: search

I have a dataset as this:

```
Group    Owner
ABC      John
ABC
TTT
TTT
TTT
CBS      Alen
CBS      Tim
SGD
SGD
```

Now I need search the dataset to find all rows whose Owner are ALL empty, like TTT and SGD, (not ABC because it has a row whose owner is John). But I only need select one item not all of them (better the first one). How could I do this using c#?

Comment: are there other fields in this dataset? as currently, this will have duplicate records (not allowed)?

Comment: of course it has other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified a database, I'll use MySQL5.6 in `sqlfiddle.com` but the approach would most likely be similar in any relational database.

First, let's set up the schema:

```
create table x (grp varchar(10), ownr varchar(10), row int);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('abc', 'john', 1);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('abc', '', 2);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('ttt', '', 3);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('ttt', '', 4);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('ttt', '', 5);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('cbs', 'alan', 6);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('cbs', 'tim', 7);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('sgd', '', 8);
insert into x (grp, ownr, row) values ('sgd', '', 9);
```

The first step is to get a list of the groups that you *don't* want in the output. The query for that would be:

```
select distinct grp from x where ownr <> ''

grp
---
abc
cbs
```

So then you simply ask for all rows with a group *other* than those (I'll also order by row here):

```
select * from x where grp not in (
    select distinct grp from x where ownr <> ''
) order by row
```

and that gets you all the other rows:

```
grp  ownr  row
---  ----  ---
ttt          3
ttt          4
ttt          5
sgd          8
sgd          9
```

Now here's where it becomes *slightly* unclear what you want. If you just want the first of that overall set, you can simply use a limiting clause such as:

```
select * from x where grp not in (
    select distinct grp from x where ownr <> ''
) order by row limit 1

grp  ownr  row
---  ----  ---
ttt          3
```

If, however, you need the first of each *group,* it can be done with an aggregating clause as follows:

```
select grp, '' as ownr, min(row) as row
from x where grp not in (
    select distinct grp from x where ownr <> ''
) group by grp

grp  ownr  row
---  ----  ---
sgd          8
ttt          3
```

Obviously I've made certain assumptions about things like:

- what an empty owner is;
- what you consider the "first" of each subset to be; and
- which database you're using for a back end.

But the *general* approach should remain the same even if those assumptions need to be modified.